# Import git project into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, github, gitlab, github-for-windows

I am importing a git project into Eclipse using a git URL. It is giving me the below errors in a popup.

1. Incorrect URL
2. No Network Connection (wrong proxy connection)
3. SSH is not configured correctly.

I have checked that the URL is correct. How to check the remaining 2 options?

Comment: In _Window > Preferences_ you can search/filter for `proxy` and `ssh`. Do you use a proxy to connect with the internet? Which URL (at least tell, which protocol)?

Comment: Can you clone from the remote on command line, e.g. git bash in Windows or bash in Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Try testing each error-message suggestion one by one:

1. Confirm the URL again. Never hurts.
2. Connect to the host machine (or website) where your repo lives from *outside of* Eclipse. If you can't do this, your connection to the host is probably the issue. If you can, the issue is not with your connection.
3. Clone the git repo to your machine directly: open a command prompt, navigate to a temporary folder, and `git clone <URL>`, where  is the SSH address you have confirmed. If the repo clones successfully, SSH is working fine on your machine, and it's time to look at Eclipse, and the information you're passing it.

If you provide more information on your environment, network configuration (esp. re: proxies, as @howlger suggests), SSH configuration, *and the settings you are passing to Eclipse*, the community may be better able to assist with your specific case.